# Form gets submitted even if validation fails

Tags: javascript, forms

I want the username and password to be `admin` & `admin` respectively so as to successfully submit the form. But the form gets submitted even if username and password to not match `admin` & `admin`.

```
function validateOnSubmit() {

    console.log("Called!");
    var isValid = true;

    document.getElementById("alert").className = "";
    if (document.getElementById("login-password").value.length <= 4) {
        isValid = false;
        document.getElementById("alert").className = "doWiggle";
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("alert").className = document.getElementById("alert").className.replace('doWiggle', '');
        }, 300);
    }else
    {
        if(document.getElementById("login-password").value != "admin" && document.getElementById("username").value != "admin") {
            alert("Wrong Password!");
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    console.log(isValid);
    return isValid;
}
```

`HTML`

```
    <div class="container">
    <form action="home.html" id="login-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateOnSubmit()">
    <p class="form-header">Sign In</p>
        <span>Username</span>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" required/>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <span>Password</span>
        <br/>
        <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" onkeyup="return validate()" required/>
        <p id="alert">Password should more than 4 characters!</p>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" class="rememberMe" id="rememberMe"/>
        <label for="rememberMe">Remember Me</label>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign In"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="options">
            <a href="register.html">Not registered ?</a>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="login">
    </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where do you call `validateOnSubmit` ?

Comment: share your html code

Comment: If you are calling your function in an event handler, you will propably have to add `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: The logic is wrong. You need to use `||` if you are checking if they are opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The way you need to call the `validateOnSubmit()` is this way:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateOnSubmit();">
```

Notice the `return` on the `onsubmit` event. Best guess would you would have forgotten the `return` keyword, which is not the same and it submits the `<form>`.

I also see you are using `className`. It is better to replace it with [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
element.classList.add(); // Similar to adding class.
element.classList.remove(); // Similar to removing class.
```

Or if you wanna toggle it, you can use:

```
element.classList.toggle();
```

**Logic**

The logic you have used is wrong:

```
if (document.getElementById("login-password").value != "admin" && document.getElementById("username").value != "admin") {
```

The above logic will not work. Use the following:

```
if (document.getElementById("login-password").value != "admin" || document.getElementById("username").value != "admin") {
```

It should be `||` operator here. Currently if any one of the `username` or `password` is right, then the form submits, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have no js errors. Your js function can be ignored if that happens.

As said above, `validateOnSubmit()` must be called somehow. The propper way is:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateOnSubmit();">
```